# ERROR: Actions invariably access the repository. Doing so without a transaction is not recommended

Tags: java, alfresco

I am trying to call action in my java class:
public void execute() {

```
    System.out.println("ScheduledJobExecuter_imapWF se poslusne hlasi");
    
    //potrebuju nejaky noderef
    ResultSet resSet = searchService.query(StoreRef.STORE_REF_WORKSPACE_SPACESSTORE, SearchService.LANGUAGE_FTS_ALFRESCO, 
            "PATH:\" /app:company_home/st:sites/cm:sparta/cm:documentLibrary\"");
    if(resSet.length() != 1){
        throw new AlfrescoRuntimeException("Nasel jsem spatny pocet veci...resSet.length() != 1 (Error n420)");
    }
    NodeRef actionedUponNoderef = resSet.getNodeRef(0);

    //volam akci 
    Action a = actionService.createAction("get_mail_imap");
    
    //actionService.executeAction(a,actionedUponNoderef);
    AuthenticationUtil.runAs(new AuthenticationUtil.RunAsWork<Object>() {
        public Object doWork() throws Exception {
            actionService.executeAction(a,actionedUponNoderef);
            return null;
        }
    }, AuthenticationUtil.getAdminUserName()); 

}
```

but highlighted line: `actionService.executeAction(a,actionedUponNoderef);`
throws an ERROR:

```
sparta-acs_1       | 2021-01-11 11:26:00,089  ERROR [quartz.core.JobRunShell] [DefaultScheduler_Worker-2] Job DEFAULT.org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.JobDetailFactoryBean#46bdcf89 threw an unhandled Exception:
sparta-acs_1       |  java.lang.IllegalStateException: Actions invariably access the repository.  Doing so without a transaction is not recommended.
sparta-acs_1       |    at org.alfresco.repo.action.executer.ActionExecuterAbstractBase.execute(ActionExecuterAbstractBase.java:251)
sparta-acs_1       |    at org.alfresco.repo.action.ActionServiceImpl.directActionExecution(ActionServiceImpl.java:856)
sparta-acs_1       |    at org.alfresco.repo.action.ActionServiceImpl.executeActionImpl(ActionServiceImpl.java:757)
sparta-acs_1       |    at org.alfresco.repo.action.ActionServiceImpl.executeAction(ActionServiceImpl.java:581)
sparta-acs_1       |    at org.alfresco.repo.action.ActionServiceImpl.executeAction(ActionServiceImpl.java:567)
sparta-acs_1       |    at org.alfresco.repo.action.ActionServiceImpl.executeAction(ActionServiceImpl.java:865)
sparta-acs_1       |    at cz.signia.sparta.jobs.ScheduledJobExecuter_imapWF$1.doWork(ScheduledJobExecuter_imapWF.java:57)
sparta-acs_1       |    at org.alfresco.repo.security.authentication.AuthenticationUtil.runAs(AuthenticationUtil.java:602)
sparta-acs_1       |    at cz.signia.sparta.jobs.ScheduledJobExecuter_imapWF.execute(ScheduledJobExecuter_imapWF.java:55)
sparta-acs_1       |    at cz.signia.sparta.jobs.ScheduledJob_imapWF$1.doWork(ScheduledJob_imapWF.java:35)
sparta-acs_1       |    at org.alfresco.repo.security.authentication.AuthenticationUtil.runAs(AuthenticationUtil.java:602)
sparta-acs_1       |    at cz.signia.sparta.jobs.ScheduledJob_imapWF.execute(ScheduledJob_imapWF.java:33)
sparta-acs_1       |    at org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.run(JobRunShell.java:202)
sparta-acs_1       |    at org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread.run(SimpleThreadPool.java:573)
```

Do you have any idea how to resolve this problem ?

Thanks

Comment: Are you calling action from scheduler or webscript?

Answer (score 0):

Hope you have the webscript transaction value as **readwrite**,

```
<webscript>
  <shortname>{}</shortname>
  <description>{}</description>
  <url>/{name}</url>
  <format default="json">argument</format>
  <authentication>user</authentication>
  <transaction allow="readwrite" buffersize="0">required</transaction>
</webscript>
```

Comment: Also if you trying to run in  client side it won't work, it will only work in the server side.

Comment: 2i do not use webscript. Java code is an executer which is called periodically. When I call my action from different java everything works. I think problem will be in calling action periodically, but I do not know how to resolve it

Answer (score 0):

Execute a unit of work as a given user. The thread's authenticated user will be returned to its normal state after the call.

```
final Context cx = Context.getCurrentContext();
        final Scriptable scope = getScope();
 
        RunAsWork<Object> raw = new RunAsWork<Object>() {
            public Object doWork() throws Exception {
                func.call(cx, scope, scope, new Object[] {});
                return null;
            }
        };
 
        AuthenticationUtil.runAs(raw, AuthenticationUtil.getAdminUserName());
    }
```